# Phoenix: ** (Mix) Could not find migrations directory "priv/repo/migrations"

Tags: phoenix-framework, circleci

When running my tests on Circle CI for a cleanly generated Phoenix project I get:

```
$ mix test
==> connection
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated connection app
==> gettext
Compiling 1 file (.erl)
Compiling 20 files (.ex)
Generated gettext app
===> Compiling ranch
==> poolboy (compile)
==> decimal
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated decimal app
==> poison
Compiling 4 files (.ex)
warning: HashDict.size/1 is deprecated, use maps and the Map module instead
  lib/poison/encoder.ex:283

Generated poison app
==> db_connection
Compiling 23 files (.ex)
warning: module attribute @regulator was set but never used
  lib/db_connection/sojourn.ex:39

Generated db_connection app
==> phoenix_pubsub
Compiling 12 files (.ex)
Generated phoenix_pubsub app
===> Compiling cowlib
===> Compiling cowboy
==> mime
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated mime app
==> plug
Compiling 44 files (.ex)
Generated plug app
==> phoenix_html
Compiling 8 files (.ex)
Generated phoenix_html app
==> phoenix
Compiling 60 files (.ex)
Generated phoenix app
==> postgrex
Compiling 61 files (.ex)
Generated postgrex app
==> ecto
Compiling 69 files (.ex)
Compiling lib/ecto/query/builder/lock.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/query/builder/filter.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/repo/preloader.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/migration/runner.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/migration/schema_migration.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Compiling lib/ecto/changeset.ex (it's taking more than 10s)
Generated ecto app
==> phoenix_ecto
Compiling 4 files (.ex)
Generated phoenix_ecto app
==> martinffx
Compiling 15 files (.ex)
Generated martinffx app
** (Mix) Could not find migrations directory "priv/repo/migrations"
for repo Martinffx.Repo.

This may be because you are in a new project and the
migration directory has not been created yet. Creating an
empty directory at the path above will fix this error.

If you expected existing migrations to be found, please
make sure your repository has been properly configured
and the configured path exists.
```

but when running the same command locally it runs successfully:

```
$ mix test
....

Finished in 0.1 seconds
4 tests, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 328700
```

Why? I've got no migrations to run? It works locally... what is happening?

circle.yml

```
machine:
  environment:
    PATH: "$HOME/.asdf/bin:$HOME/.asdf/shims:$PATH"

dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - ~/.asdf
    - deps
    - _build
  pre:
    - chmod +x ./circle_pre_build.sh
    - ./circle_pre_build.sh

database:
  override:
    - psql -U ubuntu < ./db/init-test.sql

test:
  override:
    - elixir -v
    - mix deps
    - node -v
    - npm -v
    - mix test
```

circle_pre_build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# http://code.parent.co/phoenix-circleci-heroku/
# Ensure exit codes other than 0 fail the build
set -e

# Check for asdf
if [ ! asdf | grep version ]
then
    git clone https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf.git ~/.asdf;

    # Add plugins for asdf
    asdf plugin-add erlang https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf-erlang.git
    asdf plugin-add elixir https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf-elixir.git
fi

# Install erlang/elixir
erlang_version=$(awk '/erlang/ { print $2 }' .tool-versions)
asdf install erlang $erlang_version
elixir_version=$(awk '/elixir/ { print $2 }' .tool-versions)
asdf install elixir $elixir_version

# Get dependencies
yes | mix deps.get
yes | mix deps.compile

# Exit successfully
exit 0
```

init-test.sql

```
DROP DATABASE martinffx_test;
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM   pg_catalog.pg_user
     WHERE  usename = 'martinffx') THEN

     CREATE ROLE martinffx LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
     ALTER USER martinffx CREATEDB;
   END IF;
END
$$;
```

software versions

```
$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:32:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.4.0

$ mix deps
* connection 1.0.4 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.0.4 (connection) a1cae722
  ok
* fs 0.9.1 (Hex package) (rebar)
  locked at 0.9.2 (fs) ed17036c
  ok
* gettext 0.13.1 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 0.13.1 (gettext) 5e0daf4e
  ok
* ranch 1.3.2 (Hex package) (rebar3)
  locked at 1.3.2 (ranch) e4965a14
  ok
* poolboy 1.5.1 (Hex package) (rebar)
  locked at 1.5.1 (poolboy) 6b461639
  ok
* decimal 1.3.1 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.3.1 (decimal) 157b3ced
  ok
* poison 2.2.0 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 2.2.0 (poison) 4763b69a
  ok
* db_connection 1.1.0 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.1.0 (db_connection) b2b88db6
  ok
* phoenix_pubsub 1.0.1 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.0.1 (phoenix_pubsub) c10ddf62
  ok
* cowlib 1.0.2 (Hex package) (rebar3)
  locked at 1.0.2 (cowlib) 9d769a1d
  ok
* cowboy 1.1.2 (Hex package) (rebar3)
  locked at 1.1.2 (cowboy) 61ac29ea
  ok
* mime 1.0.1 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.0.1 (mime) 05c39385
  ok
* plug 1.3.0 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.3.0 (plug) 6e2b01af
  ok
* phoenix_html 2.9.3 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 2.9.3 (phoenix_html) 1b5a2122
  ok
* phoenix 1.2.1 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.2.1 (phoenix) 6dc59224
  ok
* phoenix_live_reload 1.0.8 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 1.0.8 (phoenix_live_reload) 4333f9c7
  ok
* postgrex 0.13.0 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 0.13.0 (postgrex) e101ab47
  ok
* ecto 2.1.3 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 2.1.3 (ecto) ffb24e15
  ok
* phoenix_ecto 3.2.1 (Hex package) (mix)
  locked at 3.2.1 (phoenix_ecto) 6cf11d59
  ok

$ node -v
v4.2.6

$ npm -v
2.14.12
```

Comment: Can you try this: create a dummy empty file in `priv/repo/migrations` (e.g. `priv/repo/migrations/.gitkeep`), commit the new file, and then try testing on Circle CI?

Comment: thanks, that solves the symtom but I'd really like to get to the cause. why would this only show up on CI server not in my dev environment?

Comment: Posted an answer with explanation and an alternative fix @Martinffx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directories not containing any files itself or in any subdirectory are not stored by git. Since your migrations directory does not have any migrations, even if you add and commit your whole application into git, when you clone the git repo into another directory, you'll find the `priv/repo/migrations` directory does not exist. Ecto requires that this directory exist which is why you get the error you get.

In order to have git create `priv/repo/migrations`, you can create and commit a dummy file inside `priv/repo/migrations`. You can also add the following line to the pre-build shell file (before `mix compile`) to create that directory if it doesn't exist:

```
mkdir -p priv/repo/migrations
```

Comment: thanks man, your solution work great. I'm not entirely satisfied with the reasoning. why doesn't that file get generated as part of the scaffolding? why does it run locally without any issues?

Comment: I think Phoenix generators don't create a gitkeep type of file anywhere. Not 100% sure about why they chose to do that. I'm more surprised that Ecto doesn't handle that directory not existing. It runs locally because `phoenix.new` does create that directory; it's just not stored in git if it doesn't contain any files. If you clone the repo back from git to local, you should encounter the same error locally.